# how to get the LAST ID or RECENT ID being displayed in a MYSQL QUERY

Tags: php

i have a DB as below

```
id   posts
---+-------
 1 | post 1
 2 | post 2
 3 | post 3
 4 | post 4
 5 | post 5
 6 | post 6
```

below is my query to display posts above

```
  $db = dbConnect();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3";
  $result = $db->query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           $rowID = $row['id'];
           echo $row['posts'];
    }
```

which displays the result in this format

```
post 6
post 5
post 4
```

by default, it only shows the 3 recent posts, i will be adding a clickable `<div>` that says *old posts*. (similar to twitter/facebook when displaying old posts). when clicked, it will `ajax` additional 3 old posts.

the way im thinking of doing this, is to get the **last ID** being displayed, and use the last id in a query like so

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id > '.$last_id.' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

so i guess my question is, **how do i get the LATEST/RECENT ID being displayed on my query?**

im not sure if this is the correct way retrieving old posts, would appreciate if there are more easier/appropriate ways.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offset to say which three you want:

```
$offset = $countOfPostsSoFar;

SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset,3
```